# Generate pdf with pdfmake in iframe tag

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe

I have this JS and i would do like to generate pdf in a iframe tag using this js (made with pdfmake)

```
  function start(){
  var docDefinition = {
  content: [
    {
      table: {
       multiple pages

        headerRows: 1,
        widths: [ '*', 'auto', 100, '*' ],

        body: [
          [ 'First', 'Second', 'Third', 'The last one' ],
          [ 'Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 4' ],
          [ { text: 'Bold value', bold: true }, 'Val 2', 'Val 3', 'Val 4' ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
  };

   pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();

}
```

Show the pdf in this iframe:

```
  <frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
      <frame src="">
  </frameset>
```

When i click in this button:

```
<button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-default" onclick="start();">Savw</button>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I think my setup is slightly different but try this - something similar worked for me.

First, put an id on `<frame src="" id="foo">` then replace

```
// pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
var doc = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
var f = document.getElementById('foo');
var callback = function(url) { f.setAttribute('src',url); }
doc.getDataUrl(callback, doc);
```

The getDataUrl function runs the callback function with the generated url as argument. That callback should set the src attribute on your frame. My callback also includes `console.log(url);` so I can see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const targetElement = document.querySelector('#iframeContainer');
    const pdfDocGenerator = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
    pdfDocGenerator.getBuffer(function (buffer) {
        const dataUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([buffer], {
            type: "application/pdf"
        }));
        const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.src = dataUrl;
        iframe.width = "300px";
        iframe.height = docDefinition.pageSize.height;
        targetElement.appendChild(iframe);
 
        iframe.contentWindow.print();
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.